# How is the new Princeton Companion to Applied Mathematics,

Tags: partial-differential-equations

compared with the original Princeton Companion to Mathematics?

What if I could only afford one of the two books -- which should I get?

How come the authors are not actually from Princeton?

I am hoping to go into applied math research but I wonder if the original book is better to purchase.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to read about?  Check out their tables of contents.  Have you read reviews of the book, for example on Amazon?

Comment: See the review in SIAM News: https://sinews.siam.org/DetailsPage/tabid/607/ArticleID/766/Your-Companion-for-All-Things-Applied-Math.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the Princeton Companion to Mathematics. It is a masterpiece. The majority of the articles don't lecture at you, but motivate the development of their subject as if you and the author were sitting down and working out the subject together.

The Applied volume, I am afraid, is more agenda-driven ("We should have an article about X, so here is an article about X, never mind if it says anything or not"). It tends to go in for rhetoric rather than content you can get your teeth into. I had hoped to learn as much about Applied as I had about maths in general from the main Companion, but was disappointed.

(It could of course be that the very *subject* of Applied Mathematics is in terminal decline, replaced by Getting Computers To Solve Problems For You).

But there is no substitute for looking at the books. Find a friend, or a library, or a helpful bookshop that will order both books in and sell you only the one you want (it won't cost them anything except inconvenience because they can always return the other).

Comment: Thanks so much @martinkochanski :)